# Open multiple *SQL* buffers (same product)

Tags: tramp, sql, sql-interactive-mode

I connect to postgres by placing the following in a file on a remote server, opening over tramp, and executing:

```
(setq sql-connection-alist
      '((pool-my_db
         (sql-product 'postgres)
         (sql-server "localhost")
         (sql-user "postgres")
         (sql-password "postgres")
         (sql-database "my_db")
         (sql-port 5432))
))

;; emac25:
(sql-set-product-feature 'postgres :prompt-regexp "^.*=# ")

(defun sql-connect-preset (name)
  "Connect to a predefined SQL connection listed in `sql-connection-alist'"
  (eval `(let ,(cdr (assoc name sql-connection-alist))
    (noflet ((sql-get-login (&rest what)))
      (sql-product-interactive sql-product)))))

(sql-connect-preset 'pool-my_db)
```

If I execute the same script in the context of a different remote server, it just switches to the buffer for my first session.  Is there a way to open subsequent SQL sessions in a new  buffer so I can have multiple remote sql shells open at the same time?

Comment: What about renaming the *SQL* buffer before a further connection? Rename e.g. with `rename-uniquely`.  (Wild guess, 100% untested.)

Comment: Thanks @MarcoWahl but didn't work.